# Promo Code Value

Tags: expresso-store

Question about the variable "promo_code_value". When rendered in the template, it gives 4 decimal points instead of none. So for example, I want to indicate that there's a 25% discount, so in the template I write:

```
{promo_code_value}%
```

But instead of "25%", it renders "25.0000%". Is there some way to change that? Have I done something wrong? Don't know maybe if there's a configuration setting somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Number Format" plugin (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/number-format) and can use it like:

```
{exp:number_format number="{promo_code_value}"}%
```

Comment: Thanks Bhashkar. I also edited the db field directly -- the field 'value' is of type DECIMAL and set to '19,4'. I set it to '19,0' and it worked without the need for a plugin.